# C# Dynamic Keyword and Javascript

Tags: c#, dynamic

Suppose i have a javascript

```
<script language="javascript">

var Calculator =function ADD(int x,int y)
                {
                  return x+y;
                }

</script>
```

(1) using `dynamic keyword` how can i access the `"ADD()"` and pass parameters?

(2) Do i need to refer any `namespace` in order to achieve it?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Lot of videos showing some calculator demo! But I did not get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up languages.

The dynamic keyword is in C#.  You'll need to pass the C# variable values to the browser if you want JavaScript to add the numbers.  If you want to add in javascript you have to do something like:

```
<script language = "JavaScript" >

var Calculator =function ADD(int x,int y)
                {
                  return x+y;
                }


 Calculator('<%=Value1.ToString()%>', '<%=Value2.ToString()%>');

</script>
```

This is assuming Value1 and Value2 are numbers (int, short etc.);

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx

Looking at the blog entry, you can do it if there is a .net implementation of the language (like python) using the dynamic keyword.

**EDIT:**  Here is a link to the CodePlex project to put a JavaScript implementation on top of the DLR.

http://javascript.codeplex.com/

With this, using the dynamic keyword should be possible.

Comment: I thought ,I can call this Calculator object from my C# dynamic keyword

Comment: No not if the Calculator object is written in JavaScript.

Comment: Now,I can understand the real use of Dynamic